$\mathbb{P}( \sup_{1 \leq k \leq n} \frac{S_k}{\sqrt{n}} \geq \alpha ) \sim 2 \mathbb{P}(X_1 \geq \alpha)$ where $X_k$ are Gaussians.
I need to show the following lemma in order to prove the iterated logarithm law. Let $X_k$ be I.I.D Normal Gaussian random variables, define
$S_n := X_1 + \dots + X_n$,
I need to show that
$$\mathbb{P}( \sup_{1 \leq k \leq n} \frac{S_k}{\sqrt{n}} \geq \alpha ) \sim_{n \to +\infty, \alpha \to +\infty} 2 \mathbb{P}(X_1 \geq \alpha)$$
The problem is that I don't know how to estimate the LHS since the $S_k$ are not independent.

This might be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_inequality

You can prove this using the reflection principle.
Let $E$ be the event that $\sup_{1\le k\le n} n^{-1/2}S_k\ge\alpha$. Then, decompose $E$ into these two disjoint events.
$$
E_1=E\cap \{n^{-1/2}S_n\ge \alpha\}\\
E_2=E\cap \{n^{-1/2}S_n< \alpha\}
$$
Note that $$\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb P}\P(E_1)\le \P(n^{-1/2}S_n\ge \alpha)=\P(X_1\ge \alpha).$$ Therefore, we will be done if we can also prove that $\P(E_2)\le \P(X_1\ge \alpha)$.
Given that $E_2$ occurs, let $$t=\min\{k \mid n^{-1/2}S_k\ge\alpha\}.$$ Then, we define the reflected process to be the result of negating all of the steps after $t$. That is, the reflected process is $\hat S_0,\hat S_1,\dots,\hat S_n$, where
$$
\hat X_i=\begin{cases}X_i & i\le t \\ -X_i & i > t\end{cases}\quad,\\ 
\hat S_k=\hat X_1+\dots+\hat X_k.
$$
Let $\hat E_2$ denote the image of the event $E_2$ under this reflection operation. We can think of $E_2$ and $\hat E_2$ as subsets of $\mathbb R^n$, and the probabilities of $E_2$ and $\hat E_2$ can both be computed as an integral of the joint pdf of $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ over these subsets. Since the value of the joint pdf at a point $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is the same as the pdf value at the reflected point $(\hat x_1,\dots,\hat x_n)$, it follows that $\mathbb P(E_2)=\mathbb P(\hat E_2)$.
The event $E_2$ consists of vectors $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ whose
cumulative sums rise above $n^{1/2}\alpha$ at some point, but end below $n^{1/2}\alpha$. Therefore, the reflected event $\hat E_2$ consists of sequences whose cumulative sums rise above $n^{1/2}\alpha$ at some point, and also end above $n^{1/2}\alpha$. In particular, since all points of $\hat E_2$ are vectors whose sum is at least $n^{1/2}\alpha$, we have
$$
\mathbb P(E_2)=\mathbb P(\hat E_2)\le P(S_n\ge n^{1/2}\alpha)=P(X_1\ge \alpha)
$$
We are now done, as $P(E)=P(E_1)+P(E_2)\le P(X_1\ge \alpha)+P(X_1\ge \alpha)=2P(X_1\ge \alpha)$.
